# C++ SDL2 Net: Integer Array over TCP

Tags: c++, arrays, sockets, tcp

I'm trying to add networking to my project; more specifically, sending grid information, in the form of an integer array (`[x, y, ...]`), to the server for processing. The only comprehensive guide I found to SDL2 Net using TCP sends strings, and uses this code to convert a string to a `void *`:

```
void* ConvertStringToVoidPtr(const std::string &str)
{
    const char* charPtr = str.c_str();

    return const_cast<char*>(charPtr);
}
```

I learned that the library requires the data to be in the form of a `void *`, and it's my understanding that the conversion should be pretty simple. However, I cannot figure out how to convert this sample code into a function that accepts an array of integers:

```
void Send(std::string str)
{
    // Cast our std::string to void* so that SDL_net can understand it properly
    void *messageData = ConvertStringToVoidPtr(str);
    int messageSize = static_cast<int> (str.length());

    int bytesSent = SDLNet_TCP_Send(tcpSocket, messageData, messageSize);

    std::cout << "Trying to send " << str << "\tsent : " << bytesSent << std::endl;
    if (bytesSent < messageSize)
    {
        std::cout << "\tSend failed: " << SDLNet_GetError() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

For example, using the function:

```
void *ConvertIntArrayToVoidPtr(const int &numb[4])
{
    const int *intPtr = &numb[];

    return const_cast<int*>(intPtr);
}
```

Gives me: `error: declaration of 'numb' as array of references`. Should I try to typecast the array as a `char *`, use the existing functions, and then typecast back to an `int array[4]`?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use an integer array name as void pointer via 'array decay' to a pointer

```
int arr[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
void* intPtr = arr;
```

it is another question, how to pass an array as a parameter to the function. You'll also need the array byte length, which you can get with `sizeof`:

```
int len = sizeof arr;
```

Answer (score 0):

A generic pointer such as void* can contain any type of memory so the functions:

> void *ConvertIntArrayToVoidPtr(const int &numb[4])
>
>   void* ConvertStringToVoidPtr(const std::string &str)

they are not necessary, now in the function `void Send(std::string str)` it would be like this:

```
void Send(const void *Data, const size_t Size)
{
    int Bytes = SDLNet_TCP_Send(TcpSocket, Data, Size);
    std::cout << "Trying to send " << str << "\tsent : " << Bytes << std::endl;
    if (Bytes < Size)
    {
        std::cout << "\tSend failed: " << SDLNet_GetError() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

You would make the Send call in this way:

```
int n = 15;
Send(&n, sizeof(int));

string s = "Hello Word";
Send(s.data(), s.size());

int ar[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
Send(ar, sizeof(ar));

vector<int> v{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
Send(v.data(), v.size() * sizeof(int));
```

and so on.

Comment: Could you translate this into English, please? The question was asked so you should answer in English to help the creator understand your problem.